# Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' when loading .lottie files

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, lottie

I have a NextJS application and I'm using this [dotLottie player](https://github.com/dotlottie/player-component). I've followed the configuration steps provided in the documentation, but I keep receiving this error when the component tries to load the dotLottie file.

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
```

My global.d.ts file contains:

```js
declare module "*.lottie";
declare namespace JSX {
  interface IntrinsicElements {
    "dotlottie-player": any;
  }
}
```

In my component:

```js
import SampleLottie from "./../../../public/images/SampleLottie.lottie";

...

<dotlottie-player
  src={SampleLottie}
  autoplay
  loop
/>
```

I'm not sure what else I need to do to load the `.lottie` file correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by updating my `next.config.js` file:

```js
const nextConfig = {
  ...
  webpack: (config, options) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.lottie$/,
      type: "asset/resource",
    });

    return config;
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```